# 'select all' and 'remove all' with fastselect js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

I am using [Fast select](http://dbrekalo.github.io/fastselect/)  jQuery plugin for select elements. Is there any way to add **select all items in list** or **remove all items in list** feature to multiple select inputs?

This is code for Multiple Select inputs

```
<select class="multipleSelect" multiple name="language">
    <option value="All">Select ALLoption>
    <option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
    <option selected value="Barbados">Barbados</option>
    <option selected value="Belarus">Belarus</option>
    <option value="Belgium">Belgium</option>
    ...
</select>
```

and code for selecting input

```
$('.multipleSelect').fastselect();
```

Comment: You forgot to include your code in the question

Comment: Alan is this ok now ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a Common div to wrap the select element like the code below, and dynamically click every element in the select drop down of the plugin class to all options. Click the 'x' Button to remove all the selected values .The wrapper is to prevent the other fast select elements to be triggered in the same page you can call the below script on click of any check mark or any element separately

```
<div id="fastSelectWrapper">
    <select class="multipleSelect" multiple name="language">
    <option value="All">Select ALL</option>
    <option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
    <option selected value="Barbados">Barbados</option>
    <option selected value="Belarus">Belarus</option>
    <option value="Belgium">Belgium</option>
    </select>
    </div>
 <script>
 // to select all 
 $("#fastSelectWrapper .fstResultItem").click();
  // to remove all 
 $("#fastSelectWrapper .fstChoiceRemove").click();
 </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this independently of the plugin:

```js
$('.multipleSelect').change(e => {
  const _self = $(e.target); /* cache target */
  const _selfVal = _self.val()[0]; /* cache value */
  if (_selfVal === "All") { /* if All, select all */
    _self.find('option').prop('selected', true);
  } else if (_selfVal === "Remove") { /* if Remove, select none */
    _self.find('option').prop('selected', false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="multipleSelect" multiple name="language">
    <option value="All">Select ALL</option>
    <option value="remove">Remove ALL</option>
    <option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
    <option selected value="Barbados">Barbados</option>
    <option selected value="Belarus">Belarus</option>
    <option value="Belgium">Belgium</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I want to implement it with fast select ,please go through http://dbrekalo.github.io/fastselect/#section-examples  and look on Multiple selectable options .I want to select All Countries if user select is ALL Option

Comment: question was specifically about fast select.